# Problems installing MiKTeX

Tags: errors, installing, miktex

I have managed to download the ProTeX package and install TeXstudio. However, I keep failing in installing MiKTeX. (I have tried to download it several times from different places to insure that it was not due to errors in the file.)

The file report is

```
Loading package database...
starting package maintenance...
installation directory: "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9_3"
package repository: C:\Users\roenholt\AppData\Local\Temp\mik8802
visiting repository C:\Users\roenholt\AppData\Local\Temp\mik8802...
repository type: local package repository
loading lightweight database...
lightweight database digest: 619596a31709591ed2c339e41c0fb1d7
going to install 9522 file(s) (159 package(s))
problem: C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9_3\miktex/bin\MiKTeX209-core-PS.dll does not exist
problem: C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9_3\miktex/bin\MiKTeX209-core.dll does not exist
problem: C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9_3\miktex/bin\MiKTeX209-packagemanager-PS.dll does not exist
problem: C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9_3\miktex/bin\MiKTeX209-packagemanager.dll does not exist
extracting files from ae.tar.lzma...
extracting files from amsfonts.tar.lzma...
extracting files from amslatex.tar.lzma...
extracting files from avantgar.cab...
extracting files from babel.tar.lzma...
extracting files from bidi.tar.lzma...
extracting files from bookman.cab...
extracting files from carlisle.tar.lzma...
extracting files from cbcoptic.tar.lzma...
extracting files from cm.tar.lzma...
extracting files from courier.tar.lzma...
extracting files from dehyph-exptl.tar.lzma...
extracting files from ec.tar.lzma...
extracting files from elhyphen.tar.lzma...
extracting files from enctex.tar.lzma...
extracting files from euenc.tar.lzma...
extracting files from eurosym.tar.lzma...
extracting files from float.cab...
extracting files from fontspec.tar.lzma...
extracting files from geometry.tar.lzma...
extracting files from graphics.tar.lzma...
extracting files from helvetic.cab...
extracting files from hoekwater.tar.lzma...
extracting files from hyperref.tar.lzma...
extracting files from hyph-utf8.tar.lzma...
extracting files from ifxetex.tar.lzma...
extracting files from jknappen.cab...
extracting files from latex-fonts.tar.lzma...
extracting files from latex2e-help-texinfo.tar.lzma...
extracting files from lm.tar.lzma...
extracting files from ltxbase.tar.lzma...
extracting files from ltxmisc.tar.lzma...
extracting files from lua-alt-getopt.tar.lzma...
extracting files from luainputenc.tar.lzma...
extracting files from lualibs.tar.lzma...
extracting files from luamplib.tar.lzma...
extracting files from luaotfload.tar.lzma...
extracting files from luatexbase.tar.lzma...
extracting files from luatextra.tar.lzma...
extracting files from mflogo.cab...
extracting files from miktex-arctrl-bin-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-biber-bin.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-bibtex-base.cab...
extracting files from miktex-bibtex-bin-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-bibtex8bit-base.cab...
extracting files from miktex-bibtex8bit-bin-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-bin-2.9.tar.lzma...

Error: Permission denied: C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9_3\miktex/bin/internal/miktex-update.exe
```

Does anyone in this forum have an idea of how to solve the problem?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: How did you get `\miktex/bin`? Shouldn't it be `\miktex\bin`? Do you use windows 7? If so do you have admin rights? Do you have miktex already installed or is it a fresh install? If not a fresh install, are you using `update` or `package manager`?

Comment: Thanks for reply!

I have no idea of how I get \miktex/bin. I just followed the instructions for downloading and installing. 

I use windows 7 and have admin rights. I use a fresh install.

Comment: I must second Harish: The slash looks very dubious. Please see in `C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9_3\miktex\bin\ `, whether the files exist. It may a problem of ProTeX, but I don’t know it. You could also download the basic installer of MiKTeX directly from http://miktex.org/ and try an installation (or, if you are confident, the net installer for full installation), but I think, in TeXStudio you need to adjust the paths yourself then. Then there is the potential user right issue. _(Strange and main dir name BTW, usually without manual changes it would be `MiKTeX 2.9`.)_

Comment: _(Remove “and” in the last sentence of latest comment.)_ Some hints: Perhaps it’s better to do an installation out of `Program Files` (something like `C:\MiKTeX\ ` or `C:\LaTeX\MiKTeX\ `, avoid if possible spaces in path), and if you are the only user, then choose installation for one user, take a look at [Difference between administrative and user mode of MiKTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67712/difference-between-administrative-and-user-mode-of-miktex).

Comment: I got the same error when installing the current MiKTeX (Basic MiKTeX Installer, 2.9.4757) under Windows XP.

Answer (score 4):

A good candidate for the source of the problem, which we have found after a few hours (!) of testing, is... the virus scanner! Ours didn't allow under no circumstances to create executable files during the MikTeX installation -- even not in [admin mode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67712/difference-between-administrative-and-user-mode-of-miktex). Just after turning it off everything went smoothly.

A [quick search](https://startpage.com/do/search?query=miktex+%22virus+scanner%22) found the following links: [1](http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/forum.php?thread_name=CACXBLzhCfGM4OdqAUsaRG5oBgJoP%2BuL5o0_AHz9OQrpDWYSXGA%40mail.gmail.com&forum_name=miktex-users) [2](http://sourceforge.net/p/miktex/bugs/1935/) [3](http://www.latex-community.org/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=3030&start=10)

See also: [Is it necessary to disable virus scanner during TeX Live installation, and if so, why?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69403/is-it-necessary-to-disable-virus-scanner-during-tex-live-installation-and-if-so)

Comment: See also this comment of Paulo Cereda under the linked question: [Is it necessary to disable virus scanner during TeX Live installation, and if so, why?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/149585).

Comment: This worked for me. Also, if anyone reading this is still in the dark ages like I am, and uses Windows Vista, you need to get Service Pack 2 before attempting to download MikTeX. Doing this and turning off my virus scanner during installation solved all my problems.

Answer (score 3):

May it's because you've selected "Yes" instead of "Ask me First" when installing MikTeX. This may cause somehow Problems with the automatic update function of packages.

Try the Installation with "Ask me first" instead of "Yes". This solved the Problem in case.

My error code was: `Permission denied: C:\Miktex\source\latex\jknappen\jknappen-src.cab`